# Conditional probabilities: What is the meaning of P(X1,X2) and P(X1|X2)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have this:

$$X_1 = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \overline{E_2}
\\ 1 & E_2 \end{matrix}\right.$$$$
X_2 = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 1 & \overline{E_2} \cap \overline{E_3}
\\ 2 & \overline{E_2} \cap E_3
\\ 3 & otherwise\end{matrix}\right.  $$

And I'm asked to calculate the probabilities $P(X_2,X_1)$ and $P(X_2|X_1)$

But I don't know what the comma or the | mean here.

Is the comma something like all possible combinations, for example $P(X_2=1, X_1=0), ... , P(X_2=3, X_1=1)$? As fot the bar I don't have a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your guess for  the first part is correct. For the second part you have to find $P(X_2=1|X_1=0)=\frac {P(X_2=1,X_1=0)} {P(X_1=0)}$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what should I do on the otherwise case? Like $P(X_2=3,X_1=0)$

Comment: @user8804 You can check that $X_2=3,X_1=0$ can never occur. So probability of this is $0$.